# Use dplyr to sort tallyed data on factor level

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
    structure(list(sample = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A1", "B1", "C1", "D2"), class = "factor"), 
    genotype = structure(c(4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L), .Label = c("germline_private", "germline_recurrent", 
    "somatic_normal", "somatic_tumour"), class = "factor"), n = c(5L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), vars = "sample", drop = TRUE, .Names = c("sample", 
"genotype", "n"), indices = list(c(2L, 4L, 9L), c(1L, 5L), 6:8, 
    c(0L, 3L)), group_sizes = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 3L, labels = structure(list(
    sample = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A1", "B1", "C1", "D2"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), vars = "sample", drop = TRUE, .Names = "sample"))
```

---

```
head(df) 

sample event_no           genotype
A1        1     somatic_tumour
A1        2 germline_recurrent
A1        3 germline_recurrent
A1        4     somatic_tumour
A1        5 germline_recurrent
A1        6   germline_private
```

In this example, I want to tally the number of times genotype occurs in each sample, and then **sort so that the samples are ordered by the number of `somatic_tumour` events**

Here's what I have:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(sample, genotype) %>%
  tally %>%
  arrange(-n)
```

I then want to plot these counts for each sample, faceted by ~genotype:

```
p <- ggplot(df)
p <- p + geom_histogram(aes(sample, n), stat = "identity")
p <- p + facet_wrap(~genotype)
p
```

[image]

However, I want the samples in all panels to be sorted by the counts in the bottom right plot (`somatic_tumour`)

Comment: what is exactly your criteria? `genotype` in a specific order?

Comment: What do you mean by *sort the dataframe by this count for the genotype somatic_tumour*?

Comment: @Sotos I mean that I'm trying to arrange the df so that the samples are ordered by the number of `somatic_tumour` events

Comment: I added an answer. Have a look

Comment: @fugu, I added an answer with sorted x axis labels.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by creating a `new_n` by replacing the `n` of all except `somatic_tumour` with 0, and sort on the 2 `n`s, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(sample, genotype) %>% 
 tally() %>% 
 mutate(new_n = replace(n, genotype != 'somatic_tumour', 0)) %>% 
 arrange(-new_n, -n) %>% 
 select(-new_n)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 11 x 3
> # Groups:   sample [4]
>    sample genotype               n
>    <fct>  <fct>              <int>
>  1 A1     somatic_tumour         2
>  2 B1     somatic_tumour         2
>  3 D2     somatic_tumour         2
>  4 B1     germline_recurrent     4
>  5 A1     germline_recurrent     3
>  6 D2     germline_recurrent     3
>  7 C1     germline_private       2
>  8 C1     germline_recurrent     2
>  9 C1     somatic_normal         2
> 10 A1     germline_private       1
> 11 D2     somatic_normal         1
> ```

Comment: Thanks - this works for sorting the `df`, but the order of the samples is not changed in my plot.

Comment: Therefore, you should probalby order the factor levels of `sample` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a `left_join` to add the number of occurrences of the `somatic_tumour` in each sample. Afterwards you use the `n` column of the `somatic_tumour` observations to create an ordered vector. Thus, the x axis is arranged accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% filter(genotype == "somatic_tumour") %>% select(n, sample), 
            by = "sample") %>% 
  arrange(-n.y, -n.x) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(sample = ordered(sample, 
                          df %>% filter(genotype == "somatic_tumour") %>% 
                            arrange(n) %>% 
                            select(sample) %>% 
                            as_vector(.))) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(sample, n.x), stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~genotype)
```

**Note:** here `NA` labels are introduced, probably due to the small sample.

[image]